# Call random function on percents?

Tags: php, random

I cannot figure this out.

I need a solution to call a random function for it's percent.

Ex. there is 10% chances that the script calls subscriptions() and 3% chance that the system call the function "specialitems()".

I am stuck in this, so i hope someone can help me with this brainkiller.

```
<?php
   class RandomGifts {
   public $chances = '';

   public function __construct($user) {
          $this->user = $user;

          //Find percent for each function
          $this->chances = array( 
                 'subscriptions' => 10, // 10%
                 'specialitems'  => 3,  //  5%
                 'normalitems'   => 30, // 40%
                 'fuser'         => 50, // 70%
                 'giftcards'     => 7,  //  7%
          );

 //This should call the function which has been calculated.
 self::callFunction(?);

 }

   public function subscriptions(){}
   public function specialitems(){}
   public function normalitems(){}
   public function fuser(){}
   public function giftcards(){}

}
?>
```

Comment: The percentages in comments don't match the actual values. Why are the comments there at all?

Comment: just add the homework question so it can help us get a better understanding of what your trying to do.

Comment: I think my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$a = rand(1, 100);
$total = 0;
$f = '';
foreach($this->chances as $function => $percent) {
    $total += $percent;
    if($a <= $total) {
        $f = $function;
        break;
    }
}
if(!empty($f))
    $this->$f();
```

The percentages shouldn't add to anything above 100. If the sum is under 100, then the remaining percentage is "do nothing."

Comment: I like this solution because it's simple, but wouldn't it not be completely 'random', since it would depend on the ordering of the chances?

Comment: @kennypu No, since `$a` is random.

Answer (score -1):

Then to call a function with your class and $var name just do.

```
$this->$var();
```